# SingPath: make a JSON Object with a property "message" and a value "hello world"

Tags: json

I am beginner trying to complete a simple JSON problem on SingPath which asks that I make a JSON Object with a property "message" and a value of "hello world".  I have tried the following code:

jsonStr = {"message":"hello world"}

but I get a TypeError ==> TypeError: expected string or buffer
Could someone please help me get started? or figure out what I should correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the JSON questions in Singpath require you to submit your JSON object in the form of a string, which is the reason why you are having that error.

Try adding a single quote (') around your JSON object in your answer, and Singpath should accept your answer.

i.e.

```
jsonStr = '{"message":"hello world"}'
```

Cheers,

Daniel